# Notation in Fulton's Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, algebraic-curves

The notation in Fulton's Algebraic Curves 1.7(a) is confusing me to the point where I cannot even make examples in order to begin:

Let $k$ be a field, $F\in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$, $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in k$. Show that

$$F=\sum\lambda_{(i)}(X_1-a_1)^{i_1}\ldots(X_n-a_n)^{i_n}\hspace{10px},\hspace{10px}\lambda_{(i)}\in k.$$

Can someone give an example polynomial written into this form so I can make sense of the odd indices?

Comment: Is $k$ algebraically closed?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Are you merely constructing an $F$, or proving that all $F$'s have this form?  (The latter I don't believe.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\lambda_{(i)}$ here refers to a constant which may change depending on the individual powers of each $X_i - a_i$ appearing in the term. That is, $(i) = (i_1,i_2,\dots, i_n),$ so $\lambda_{(i)}$ depends on each $i_j.$

As an example, let $n = 3,$ $a_1 = -1,$ $a_2 = 0,$ and $a_3 = 1,$ and let $k = \Bbb C.$ Such a polynomial is
$$
F(X_1,X_2,X_3) = (X_1 + 1)(X_2)(X_3 - 1) + 2(X_1 + 1)(X_3 - 1) - 7(X_2)^3(X_3 - 1)^{12}.
$$
Here $\lambda_{(1,1,1)} = 1,$ $\lambda_{(1,0,1)} = 2,$ and $\lambda_{(0,3,12)} = -7.$

You're writing the polynomial in a sort of Taylor expansion at the point $(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in k^n,$ and the $\lambda_{(i)}$ are the coefficients in this expansion as $(i) = (i_1,\dots, i_n)$ ranges through all the elements of $\Bbb N_0^n.$ Writing a given polynomial $p$ in this form in the situation $k = \Bbb R,$ $n = 1$ recovers the usual Taylor expansion of $p$ about the point $X = a.$

Comment: Yes. All $F$'s have this form, over any field; we don't need to take derivatives with limits. If $F$ is written as a combination of "usual" monomials $x_1^{d_1} \dotsm x_n^{d_n}$ then we can write it as $((x_1-a_1)+a_1)^{d_1} \dotsm ((x_n-a_n)+a_n)^{d_n}$, expand each product using the binomial theorem, and multiply out, to get a bunch of monomials in the $x_i-a_i$ (with coefficients involving binomial coefficients, $a_i$'s, etc.).